# VS Code Formatting JSX with new lines in useCallback()

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

VSC's jsx formatting looks weird.
If there's no param in useCallback it looks fine, but there's new line when there's param. And also there's new line in dependency array when useCallback method has params.

I want to change this as in the case where there are no parameters.
Any Ideas?

```
const onSubmitEditing = useCallback(
 ({nativeEvent}) => {
     setSearchQuery(nativeEvent.text);
  },
  [setSearchQuery],
);

const clearText = useCallback(() => {
  setSearchBoxText('');
}, [setSearchBoxText]);
```

This is my `.prettierrc.js`.
And I use 'Prettier - Code formatter' as default formatter.

```
module.exports = {
  bracketSpacing: false,
  jsxBracketSameLine: true,
  singleQuote: true,
  trailingComma: 'all',
};
```